# How to you convert from a Decision Tree to a Regression Tree?

Tags: machine-learning, cart

I have a Decision tree that is meant to work on output that are classes. How could one convert this to a Regression tree, so that it can work on continuous outputs?

I understand that the residual sum of square

Comment: "I understand that the residual sum of square" - residual sum of square what?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do something like that if the classes that your original tree predicts are actually discretized continuous data,  but I would not recommend that.  If you want a regression tree,  you should generate that from the beginning. Here is an example using R to generate a regression tree.  It uses the mtcars data to predict the mpg (miles per gallon) for the cars in the data set.

```
library(rpart)
rpart(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars)
n= 32 

node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 32 1126.04700 20.09062  
  2) cyl>=5 21  198.47240 16.64762  
    4) hp>=192.5 7   28.82857 13.41429 *
    5) hp< 192.5 14   59.87214 18.26429 *
  3) cyl< 5 11  203.38550 26.66364 *
```